# Rserve connection with Tableau Server

Tags: r, powershell, tableau-api

While publishing a workbook that contains R script to Tableau Server. i am getting  error "this rserve connection does not support authentication. try connecting without specifying a password.".I have already configured tableau server with R using powershell commands.

I have installed R on windows and cant even find its config file.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: [troubleshooting R connections](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/r_connection_troubleshoot.html) I believe that you will need to "either disable Rserve authentication or change to plaintext password authentication."

It looks like you have specified an authentication method from Tableau but not from the R side. Take a look at how to [Configure an Rserve Connection](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/r_connection_manage.html), your problem might be with this step "If the server requires credentials, specify a Username and Password."